# Aquiring state on click

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I currently have a button as follows:

```
  <div id="hidden" style="display:none"> 
        <table border="10" style="width:300px">
        <tr>
          <td>Type</td>
          <td>URL State</td>
          <td>Server State</td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        <tr>
          <td>Product</td>
          <td><%=product%></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
  </div>

window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = showState;
}

function showState()
{   
    var productServer = getSelectedProduct();

    if (document.getElementById("hidden").style.display == "block")
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
    }
}

function getProduct()
{
   return product;
}
```

On page load getProduct() returns nulls because my whole page is reset. I want that onlick for the product to return the actual product that has been selected. For example i have tried the following. Going through the debugger with the following code

```
  <div id="hidden" style="display:none"> 
        <table border="10" style="width:300px">
        <tr>
          <td>Type</td>
          <td>URL State</td>
          <td>Server State</td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        <tr>
          <td>Product</td>
          <td><%=product%></td>
          <td>getProduct()</td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
  </div>
```

When this runs I get null because when the page first loads the product is null. If I do the following:

```
function showState()
{   
    var product = getProduct();
    var productServer = getSelectedProduct();

    if (document.getElementById("hidden").style.display == "block")
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Then onclick that product variable is updated with the correct product. My question is how do I get the var product that I have in showState() method to appear in my table everytime someone clicks the button?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You are missing your button tag in your original posts code.

**2)** You do not have script tags around your JS.

**3)** Make sure you are including the JS library

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click to show states" onclick="showState();"/>

<div id="hidden" style="display: none;"> 
        <table border="10" style="width:300px">
        <tr>
          <td>Type</td>
          <td>URL State</td>
          <td>Server State</td>
        </tr>
        </br>
        <tr>
          <td>Product</td>
          <td><%=product%></td>
          <td>getProduct()</td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function showState()
{   
    if (document.getElementById("hidden").style.display == "block")
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: That is all the code I have. It didn't work with the ready function. Is there anyway to make like an id or something in the <td id="productState"> such that in the showState() function I can update that id and then use the document.getElementById("productState") in the table? I am really not sure if this would be the way to make it happen?

Comment: Which thing exactly in the HTML are you clicking? One you know which element it is, you can then give it an id.

Comment: <input type="button" id="button" value="Click to show states" onclick="showState()"/>

Comment: I am using that to click on the button

Comment: Ok, you should have put that in the HTML above... updating my post.

Comment: Updated my post.. according to what you posted for code it looks like you didn't include script tags, which would be your issue. Also, make sure you're including the JS library.

Comment: when the page is first initially loaded all parameters are null. Once loaded and items selected from drop down then I want the table to be updated with the current selected values from the drop downs. This code is returning null as of now.

Comment: Post your full code in your OP. With your code you supplied it's hard to fix your problem because you're now talking about drop down menu's and updating tables but your code has none of that. If your code is returning null on page load you should use jQuery's ready function.